# import selected data from flat file into Microsoft SQL server management studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, import

this probably is a duplicate question but I can't find the answer. Please help me! :)

I have a large dataset which I do not want to import the whole dataset into the server: 1. Takes a long time. 2. Low on virtue memory since it is from a local flat file.

Thus I would like to only import the selected data such as from a certain time period.

Here is an example:

**name, age, startdate**

**a,24,20150102**

**b,23,20150304**

**c,28,20160419**

Say I want rows only in 2015-- filter out the third row which is in 2016. How can I do that during the import (without import the whole dataset then run a select)? I am currently using wizard and bulk insert for my queries.

```
bulk insert [a].[dbo].[testdata]
from 'C:\fakepath\testdata.txt' 
with 
(firstrow=2,
fieldterminator = ',', 
rowterminator = '\n')
```

**If filtering is not achievable, cut the dataset in half during loading process is fine too.**

Please help me, thank you!

Comment: `bulk insert` is fairly inflexible, it's all or nothing. May the answer I gave here will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593116/insert-csv-file-into-sql-server-with-bulk-insert-and-reorder-columns/36594073#36594073

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The solution in the link still need to load all the data into a table. I would like to know how to partially load the data. (I can definitely use other import method than bulk insert if this is not working. :) )

Answer (score 0):

The selecting data based on criteria IS the job of the database engine. So, if you want to filter the data, then you need it in a table, so you can use the SQL Server engine.

Management Studio is NOT an engine. Is a parser. It passes the query to the engine and shows you the results.

Use FIRSTROW and LASTROW parameters of BULK INSERT to import parts of a file.

[BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

Example:

```
bulk insert [a].[dbo].[testdata]
from 'C:\fakepath\testdata.txt' 
with 
(firstrow=2000,lastrow=3000
fieldterminator = ',', 
rowterminator = '\n')
```